# bower show package dependencies tree before install

Tags: bower

Is it possible to get a list of package dependencies (as produced by `bower list`) before installing the packages?

`bower install` does not complete successfulfy in my project as some package has a dependency to a non existing package version, therefore I would like to be able to quickly find that package that has this incorrect dependency instead of having to inspect `bower.json` of every package.

Comment: I have run into the same issue again, suggestions/answers anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [bower-dependency-tree](https://github.com/shyiko/bower-dependency-tree). `npm install -g bower-dependency-tree && bower-dependency-tree name_of_the_package_you_are_interested_in` should do it.

disclosure: I am the maintainer of the project.

Comment: I would definetely give it a try. Did you find this question before creating `bower-dependency-tree` or afterwards?

Comment: @AdamSiemion We had some some serious performance issues with Bower leading to OOMs for particular packages. We wanted to take a look at the dependency tree before installing them (as we couldn't really install things because of aforementioned OOMs). I've discovered this question in attempt to find existing tool. I've found none, so I wrote a module to do what I needed it to and went back to the question to post an answer. Hopefully it could help other people to deal with this kind of problems in future.

Comment: Thanks Stanley for the contribution to the Open Source community. I have tried `bower-dependency-tree`, however it seems to fail, submitted an issue on github for that.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. Issue has been fixed.